# Geocoding Addresses with PostGIS in PgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am having trouble geocoding addresses with postgis in pgAdmin. I have the extensions postgis, postgis_tiger_geocoder, address_standardizer in pgadmin. However, I noticed that I do not have permission to access the tiger schema created from the tiger geocoder in pgadmin. I am assuming that this could be a reason why I am unable to geocode?

So, I am working in the public schema, where I created my database and table that contains addresses. My table had the address in different columns, so I ran this code to put the address into a full_address column:

```sql
UPDATE table 
SET full_address = CONCAT_WS(', ', address, city, state, zip_code, country);
```

That is set in a character varying data type.

This worked, but now I want to take that full_address and convert it into a latiitude and longitude. However, everything I tried is now working. For example, I tried this:

```sql
-- Create a new table to store geocoding results
CREATE TABLE geocoded_schools AS (
  SELECT
    ws.*,
    g.rating,
    ST_X(g.geomout) AS longitude,
    ST_Y(g.geomout) AS latitude,
    (g.addy).address AS stno,
    (g.addy).streetname AS street,
    (g.addy).streettypeabbrev AS styp,
    (g.addy).location AS geocoded_city,  
    (g.addy).stateabbrev AS st,
    (g.addy).zip AS zip,
    ws.city AS original_city  
  FROM
    schools ws
    LEFT JOIN LATERAL geocode(ws.full_address, 1) AS g ON true
);
```

Nothng is working. Long and lat columns are blank. What could be the issue?

I looked at a bunch of different tutorials and example codes, and nothing has worked.